# How can I grab the 2nd set of the price variable in this array?

Tags: php, wordpress, api

I'm grabbing info from an API and the API kicks back 2 different prices in the array, one in CAD and one in USD. The current API call only grabs the CAD price but I'm trying to get it to grab the prices in USD.

Here is the API call and how it sets the data

```
            global $resultCount;
            global $arrXml;
            $stringA = "msg";
            $stringB = "value";
            $product = "product";
            $measure = "measure";
            $title = "title";
            $a001 = "a001";
            $contributor = "contributor";
            $mediafile = "mediafile";
            $supplydetail = "supplydetail";
            $price = "price";
            $publisher = "publisher";
            $c094 = "c094";
            $resultCount = $arrXml[$stringA][0][$stringB];

            global $Book_Array;
            global $arrXml;
            global $resultAmount;
            $Book_Array[$resultAmount]['ISBN'] = $arrXml[$product]["a001"];
            $Book_Array[$resultAmount]['TITLE'] = $arrXml[$product][$title]["b030"]." ".$arrXml[$product][$title]["b031"]." ".$arrXml[$product][$title]["b203"]." ".$arrXml[$product][$title]["b029"];
            $Book_Array[$resultAmount]['PUB'] = $arrXml[$product][$publisher]["b081"];
            $Book_Array[$resultAmount]['YOP'] = $arrXml[$product]["b003"];
            $Book_Array[$resultAmount]['BOOK_SIZE'] = $arrXml[$product][$measure][0][$c094]." ".$arrXml[$product][$measure][0][$c095]." by ".$arrXml[$product][$measure][1][$c094]." ".$arrXml[$product][$measure][1][$c095]." by ".$arrXml[$product][$measure][2][$c094]." ".$arrXml[$product][$measure][2][$c095];
            $Book_Array[$resultAmount]['AUTH'] = $arrXml[$product][$contributor]["b037"]." ".$arrXml[$product][$contributor][0]["b037"]." ".$arrXml[$product][$contributor][1]["b037"];
            $Book_Array[$resultAmount]['PRICE'] = $arrXml[$product][$supplydetail][$price]["j151"];
            $Book_Array[$resultAmount]['THUMB'] = $arrXml[$product][$mediafile][0]["f117"];
            $Book_Array[$resultAmount]['IMG'] = $arrXml[$product][$mediafile][1]["f117"];
```

And here's the info it shoots back, I used Rich dad poor dad as an example:

```
<data>
    <msg>
        <num>2001</num>
        <txt>results: 1</txt>
        <value>1</value>
    </msg>
    <product>
        <a001>9781978691704</a001>
        <b012>AC</b012>
        <productidentifier>
            <b221>02</b221>
            <b244>197869170X</b244>
        </productidentifier>
        <productidentifier>
            <b221>03</b221>
            <b244>9781978691704</b244>
        </productidentifier>
        <title>
            <b203>Rich Dad Poor Dad</b203>
            <b029>20th Anniversary Edition: What the Rich Teach Their Kids About Money That the Poor and Middle Class Do Not!</b029>
        </title>
        <publisher>
            <b081>Brilliance Audio</b081>
        </publisher>
        <b003>20190514</b003>
        <b064>_AV010010</b064>
        <subject>
            <b067>10</b067>
            <b069>BUS050000</b069>
        </subject>
        <subject>
            <b067>10</b067>
            <b069>FAM034000</b069>
        </subject>
        <b056>UBR</b056>
        <measure>
            <c093>01</c093>
            <c095>in</c095>
            <c094>5.50</c094>
        </measure>
        <measure>
            <c093>02</c093>
            <c095>in</c095>
            <c094>6.50</c094>
        </measure>
        <measure>
            <c093>03</c093>
            <c095>in</c095>
            <c094>1.13</c094>
        </measure>
        <contributor>
            <b035>A01</b035>
            <b037>Kiyosaki, Robert T</b037>
            <b034>1</b034>
        </contributor>
        <contributor>
            <b035>A01</b035>
            <b037>Parks, Tom</b037>
            <b034>2</b034>
        </contributor>
        <supplydetail>
            <j137>TBM</j137>
            <price>
                <j148>01</j148>
                <j151>81.99</j151>
                <j152>CAD</j152>
            </price>
            <price>
                <j148>01</j148>
                <j151>54.97</j151>
                <j152>USD</j152>
            </price>
        </supplydetail>
        <mediafile>
            <f114>07</f114>
            <f115>03</f115>
            <f116>01</f116>
            <f117>http://bookmanager.com/i/b.php?b=BMOGSzFyXVkasX4SnRYa_w</f117>
        </mediafile>
        <mediafile>
            <f114>04</f114>
            <f115>03</f115>
            <f116>01</f116>
            <f117>http://bookmanager.com/i/m.php?b=BMOGSzFyXVkasX4SnRYa_w</f117>
        </mediafile>
    </product>
    <msg>
        <num>2003</num>
        <txt>XMLISBN_ENHAN queries remaining: 10021</txt>
        <value>10021</value>
    </msg>
</data>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

var_export() of supply detail will look like the following

```
 'supplydetail' => 
    array (
      'j137' => 'TBM',
      'price' => 
      array (
        0 => 
        array (
          'j148' => '01',
          'j151' => '81.99',
          'j152' => 'CAD',
        ),
        1 => 
        array (
          'j148' => '01',
          'j151' => '54.97',
          'j152' => 'USD',
        ),
      ),
    ),
```

USD price is in a 2nd element of price array, So to access the USD price, you need to call it using index which is 1 in given case

```
echo  $arrXml[$product][$supplydetail][$price][1]["j151"];
```

Comment: Much appreciated Indra, worked perfectly. Thank you.